# Matching string followed by a number from 1 to 49 in braces in a list of comma separated pairs?

Tags: regex

I can not find a working regular expression to match the strings followed by a number from 1 to 49 in braces, in a list dividing the pairs by comma:

`alpha (1), beta (12), gamma (37), delta (49), epsilon (55), zeta (64)`

but also in random order and amount of pairs like

`zeta (64), alpha (1), gamma (37), beta (12), delta (49), epsilon (55), eta (48), theta (26)`

and also random numbers like

`zeta (11), gamma (71), beta (49), delta (52), epsilon (99), alpha (33)`

I'm looking for an endresult showing only the pairs with a number lower as 49 like

`alpha (1), beta (12), gamma (37), delta (49)`

`alpha (1), gamma (37), beta (12), delta (49), eta (48), theta (26)`

`zeta (11), beta (49), alpha (33)`

The only part I can get working so far is the detection of the numbers 1-49 in braces:

`\(([1-9]|[1234][0-9])\)`

Is it possible to get the strings in front of the found number with a regular expression (and substitution)?

Comment: So, you want to match spaces/commas + a word followed with a number inside parentheses that is NOT between 1 and 49? `[,\s]*\w+\s+\((?!(?:[1-9]|[1234][0-9])\))\d+\)` to replace with an empty string?

Comment: You could get all the matches `\w+ \((?:[1-9]|[1234][0-9])\)(?:, )?` https://regex101.com/r/WtXXjT/1

Comment: Please explain why you only consider using a substitution. What is the environment?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew A substitution is only one possible way to achieve my goal and given endresult. If there are other ways, please let me know. It was not my intention to reduce the solution to a version with substitution only. It should only work with a regular expression without any further string manipulation in a external environment.

Comment: In Python, `', '.join([n.group() for n in re.finditer(r'\w+\s+\((\d+)\)', text) if 1 <= int(n.group(1)) <= 49])` will do it.

Comment: @PeterCo Did the pattern work out?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes it works! There are some combinations where a comma remains as the last character at the end of the list. But this should be easy to detect for a second run. Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the matches from the example data, you could optionally match a comma and one or more horizontal whitespace chars and start the match with 1 or more word characters followed by a space.

```
\w+ \((?:[1-9]|[1234][0-9])\)(?:, )?
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WtXXjT/1).

If you have a chain and you don't want to match trailing comma's, you can optionally match the comma's while asserting there is another expected format to the right:

```
\w+ \((?:[1-9]|[1234][0-9])\)(?:, (?=\w+ \(\d+\)))?
```

The pattern matches:

- `\w+`  Match 1 or more word chars and a space
- `\((?:[1-9]|[1234][0-9])\)`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `,`  Match a comma and a space
  - `(?=\w+ \(\d+\))` Positive lookahead, assert 1+ word characters, a space and one or more digits between parenthesis to the right
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hEuru7/1).

**Note** that if you want to match 1 or more whitespace characters instead of a single space, you can use `\s+` but that can also match newlines.